# How to build Photo Gallery with sliding to the left and right behavior (similat to Apple Native Photos app)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, image-gallery

I would like to build a gallery view of the photos similar to native Photos app, with possibility to slide image to left and to right. I want to display some extra buttons and label on each slide. could you advice me, please, where to dig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the pagingEnabled property in UIScrollView.